# Error: Failed to parse method 'InitializeComponent'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Call Stack:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

So I got this error pretty much out of nowhere. I can build the project and run it. I only cannot open main window designer, unlike my co-programmer (we use TFS and he has the exact same files according to TFS).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? Closing and re-opening VS?

Comment: If you are using TFS you can delete the whole work directory (including the hidden files) and get the latest version from TFS.

Comment: I have tried cleaning the project, as well as closing and re-opening VS afterwards.

Comment: I resolved the issue by shelving my work, removing all files, downloading everything from TFS and then copying my work from shelve to newly downloaded project. Not really a solution to my problem but i got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an issue similar to the title (not sure if same call stack), I was modifying designer files manually and switching between branches/doing check-ins and check outs. Don't know exactly how I caused it. I tried reverting to a previous version of the code base with no progress, cleaning the solution deleting all (non ignored files).

The cause : the hidden directory (.vs) got corrupted
The solution : Close visual studio that has this solution open. Delete the .vs directory